# HTML5 audio file loads only partially or in chunks

Tags: html5-audio

I have incorporated a playlist into a HTML page much along the lines of http://devblog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/. The actual playing of tracks is achieved via

```
player.load();
player.play();
```

Every now and then, a sound file will play only partially. Tracking that problem with several browsers, I observed the following behavior:

On Firefox,

[image]

the first line shows a partial load of the file via the playlist. The second loaded the complete file, issued from FireBug. The third, again via the playlist, loaded even less than the first. All say Status = 200, although only part of the file got transferred.

So I tried it on Chrome. There, a *single* load from the playlist yielded:

[image]

So the browser appears to have, after receiving the first part, issued another request for the same file (which has `Range: bytes=4325410-` ), and, after this didn't deliver the complete file, still another. Listening to this, I noticed two slight disruptions, probably at the section points between the partial files.

I am particularly puzzled about the entries showing Status = (failed) in this list, as I have no idea according to which rules the browser and server were communicating. I would have expected at least a valid HTTP response code.

The sound file comes from a NAS on a local network. I frequently load files of a few megabytes from there (e.g. photos), and there are no speed or stability issues.

Any hints how to further track down this behavior?